# Dynamic Vlookup Across Multiple Sheets

Tags: excel

I am building a worksheet to track employee's remaining FMLA hours balance.

I have the formula:

```
=VLOOKUP($D4,INDIRECT("'"&D5&"'!"&"D5:F5"),3,0)
```

It is pulling the correct cell but the value in it is incorrect. For example: The hours remaining is 182 and for some reason the time shows 14? If I use +(cell) it pulls the correct value...Am I missing something? Please help!

Employee ID 111111
Employee Name   Salary (Emp Name is from a vlookup off of a range)
Hours Remaining 14:00:00

data is in this format:

111111  Remaining:  182:00:00

Comment: You are doing a VLOOKUP on a single row.  Please include a mockup of the data set, it is hard to figure out the issue based solely on the formula.

Comment: The data is only in one row. 

Data:

Employee ID 111111
Employee Name Salary
Hours Remaining 14:00:00 (formula here)

pulling data from: 

111111 Remaining: 182:00:00

Comment: Then why the VLOOKUP?  Just do `INDIRECT("'"&D5&"'!F5")`

Comment: There are hundreds of tabs that are being pulled from based on name. The formula needs to be based on the employee name which is also the tab name

Comment: The issue isnt pulling the data. the issue is getting the data to show the correct value.

Comment: And the indirect takes care of that.  VLOOKUP looks down a vertical column for a match  if you only have one row then vlookup does nothing.

Comment: Tried your formula-works. thanks! however, it is still showing the wrong value.

Comment: Then your value is either in a different cell or has a different formatting than the one in which you have the formula.  Change the formatting of the cell in which you have the formula to `[hh]:mm:ss`

Comment: thank you! for some reason one was in h:mm:ss and the other was [h]:mm:ss.